# Generate graphs of n nodes with 4 edges at each node

Tags: graph-theory

I'd like to generate and count, $C_n$, connected graphs up to isomorphism with the property that each node has 4 edges and the number of nodes is $n$.

**Examples for small $n$**

$n=1, C_1 = 1$: there is only 1 such graph with 2 loops on a node

$n=2, C_2 = 2$: there are 2 such graphs, either the 2 nodes are connected by 4 edges, or by 2 edges but each node has a loop too

$n=3, C_3 = 4$: it's easier to just draw these 4 graphs than to explain in words :)

In any case is there a general formula for $C_n$?

What would be the most efficient way of generating or enumerating the graphs for given $n$?

Comment: suitable for math stackexchange

Comment: Start here: https://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/~bdm/data/intmat.html and the linked paper.

Comment: Number of isomorphism classes of connected 4-regular multigraphs of order n, loops allowed: https://oeis.org/A085549

Comment: Why the votes to close?  This is not a trivial problem, and it seems that there is no formula known (the "formula" in the OEIS entry only relates it to another sequence which also doesn't have a known formula).

Comment: @Noam, I suppose the votes to close are in view of the "no notorious open questions" rule.